# jqgrid shows "Object" for SQL time datatype returned thru json query

Tags: jquery, sql-server, json, jqgrid

I'm having issue formatting time output from my SQL server.
Data is retrieved in json and *"formatter"* and *"formatoptions"* are used to populate date and time in JQGRID as below:

```
 {
            key: false, name: 'Date_Rencontre', index: 'Date_Rencontre', align: 'right', width: 90,
            formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "d/m/Y" }
        },
        {
            key: false, name: 'Heure_Debut', index: 'Heure_Debut', align: 'right', width: 100,
            formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "HH:mm" }
        },
        {
            key: false, name: 'Heure_Fin', index: 'Heure_Fin', align: 'right', width: 100,
            formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: "ISO8601Long", newformat: "HH:mm" }
        },
```

The date part is working fine but the time part shows *"[Object Object]"*.
I've tried several options and combinations most of them returning  *"Object"* or *"NaN"*

See below my source data and the jqgrid display[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2JIV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWblu.png)

Comment: You should include the exact JSON data which will be used as the input for jqGrid and always include the information about the version of jqGrid which you use (can use) and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: I'm using the free version 4.6 of jqgrid. Here are the lines that call my controller:
                    $("#detailsRencontresDdeur")
                            .setGridParam({ url: "GetDemandeurs_MenuConseiller_RencontresSubgrid?id=" + data.Code_Demandeur, page: 1 })
                            .setCaption("<b>Détail des rencontres pour : " + data.Prenoms_Demandeur + ' ' + data.Nom_Demandeur + "</b>")
                            .trigger('reloadGrid');
                });

In this case I don't know how to display it in my console.